# how to skip confirm pop up on beforeunload and show my own bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to skip the default pop up which will come on `beforeunload` event and want to show my own modal which is asking the user to give feedback on browser/tab close. In that modal if user click "OK" then I want to redirect the user to my feedback page and if the user clicks "NO" then the particular tab should close. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload you may change the  `event.returnValue` of the `beforeunload` event to a custom string. Like this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function( event ) {
  event.returnValue = "Don't leave!";
});
```

This will open a confirm dialog when the user is leaving the current page. 
You may open your modal window in this event, but this will not stop the user form leaving, so new content will not be seen.

Of course the `unload` event can not be canceled (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) and UI interactions are ineffective (window.open, alert, confirm etc.)

So i think the closest you can get it this: http://jsfiddle.net/s6qWr/

```
var $modal = document.getElementById("modal");
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event){
    $modal.classList.add("visible"); 
    event.returnValue = "Please tell us about your experience";
});
```