# Is there any way to handle the browser/tab close other than beforeunload or onbeforeunload or unload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to handle the browser/tab close other than beforeunload or onbeforeunload or unload. because I tried all the 3 events but the default pop up is coming. I don't want that default pop up but I want do something on the close click.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to skip confirm pop up on beforeunload and show my own bootstrap modal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081449/how-to-skip-confirm-pop-up-on-beforeunload-and-show-my-own-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't outright block the closure of a window/tab with `preventDefault` or any other method. Because of this limitation, you can't use a custom modal, etc. to show a message. Your only option is to return a message, which can be bypassed.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Do you want to leave?";
}
```

(Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9sAE4/embedded/result/)

Note that Firefox does not presently show the user the included message, but rather a generic message asking if the user wishes to leave.

Comment: Thank you T.J crowder but I dont want to close the browser/tab and I want to show my own Pop up... Is There any way like that I can do

Comment: @user3899398 Not possible. what you can do inside a `beforeunload` is _very_ limited. I added a demo though.

Answer (score 1):

No. The only way to do anything when the window is closed is to use `onbeforeunload`, and the things you're allowed to do are quite limited. Firefox and Chrome prevent your using `alert` or `confirm`, for instance (but do support returning a string from the handler, which then *they'll* use to show the user the choice to stay on the page). Some browsers may allow *synchronous* `ajax` calls, but I don't think all do, and I'd avoid it if I were you. You can probably set items in local storage.

From your comment:

> I dont want to close the browser/tab and I want to show my own Pop up

You can't. All you can do is hook `onbeforeunload` and return a *string*, which the browser will use to offer the user a chance to stay on the page. You can't style that window, or control it.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Your message here.";
};
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/voboma/1)

Note that recent versions of Firefox don't even show **your** message, they just use a generic "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." (or similar) instead.